# Add an additional frontend property to the attributes - magento 1.9x

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

When adding/editing an attribute it is possible to set a number of frontend properties such as "allow HTML tags on frontend" or "used in product listing".  I would like to add some additional frontend properties. I am thinking of things like "include in pdf" and "logged in users only".

I have tried modifying  the catalog_eav_attribtes table directly and adding some new columns.  I have then overridden the

*core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catgalog/Product/Attribute/Edit/Tab/Main.php*

```
$fieldset->addField('is_in_simple_list', 'select', array(
    'name' => 'is_in_simple_list',
    'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Visible in Simple Lists on Frontend'),
    'title' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Visible in Simple Lists on Frontend'),
     'note'      => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Custom field for project'),
    'values' => $yesnoSource,
));
```

to include controls for the new fields.

However, whilst the controls appear, the value of the data does not save. Any thoughts as the the next step which I am missing and if there are any ramifications down the line to doing this?

Thanks

Comment: If I set it in the database manually then the form control correctly says "yes" but am unable to save the change made in the admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally discovered what was missing.  One needs to overwrite the Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup class

and add the new fieldname into the _prepareValues() function/method.

```
...
        'apply_to'                      => $this->_getValue($attr, 'apply_to'),
        'position'                      => $this->_getValue($attr, 'position', 0),
        'is_configurable'               => $this->_getValue($attr, 'is_configurable', 1),
        'is_used_for_promo_rules'       => $this->_getValue($attr, 'used_for_promo_rules', 0),
        'is_in_simple_list'             => $this->_getValue($attr, 'is_in_simple_list', 0),
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your core file to **app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Attribute/Edit/Tab/Main.php**

Your code is correct. Put the same code in above file.

Make sure you are using correct data type for the database table field. You can use `int(1)` for `Yes/No` field.

Use the same column name in database table as you have field name in form. e.g. add a column `is_in_simple_list` in `catalog_eav_attribute` table for **is_in_simple_list** field.

Remove `var/cache` folder manually. If you have compilation enabled, recompile your code.

Now check by changing the attribute field value and saving attribute in admin panel.

Comment: actually if you read my post I have overridden that file and not changed the core file.

Comment: What you have said is what I have already done and the field is in the DB and the form field is showing and will show the value in the DB.  However the value set in the form does not save. I guess I will need to trawl through the process step by step and see what is and is not happening.  Thanks for taking the time to respond though.

Comment: I have tried the same thing on my setup and I can save values in database. Just try to remove var/cache and var/session. It should work.

Comment: will give it another crack

Comment: Have given you the 50 rep as I offered it but haven't yet had time to look at it again as have been on another project.   I have caching switched off on my dev area anyhow.

Comment: finally got back onto this and it is not working